# Java Priority Queue behaving weirdly

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am implementing an app that finds the closest n events to a given location in an (x,y) plane, based on manhattan distance.
I am using a max PriorityQueue to store the found events, with a manhattan distance comparator. This queue should always have the max manDistance Event as its peek, however I found that this does not happen all the time.
I printed the results of this queue by using pq.poll() in a loop, and I found out that the queue is not rearranged after a removal,only sometimes.

My comparator:

```
public class LocationComparator implements Comparator<Event> {
private double xCord,yCord;

public LocationComparator(double x,double y){
    xCord=x;
    yCord=y;
}
@Override
public int compare(Event x,Event y){
    double xManDist=Math.abs(x.getxCord()-xCord)+Math.abs(x.getyCord()-yCord);
    double yManDist=Math.abs(y.getxCord()-xCord)+Math.abs(y.getyCord()-yCord);
    return (int)(yManDist-xManDist);
}
}
```

Printing it in the main method:

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Closest Events to location {0},{1}",x,y));
        while (!(events.isEmpty())){
            Event temp=events.poll();
            System.out.println(temp);
            System.out.println(temp.calcManDistance(x, y));
```

Output:

```
Closest Events to location 0,0
name: Event 5
x: 3.43
y: -4.97
8.398549367213874
name: Event 10
x: -8.98
y: -0.49
9.469052759377341
name: Event 3
x: -0.77
y: 7.92
8.693576027826397
name: Event 2
x: -0.57
y: -6.56
7.127381509823561
name: Event 6
x: -0.56
y: -3.38
3.935261527783056
```

As you can see, the events are not in descending order! However, sometimes they are. I cannot track what causes this inconsistent behaviour. Am I missing something?

In case this is relevant, I am generating the queue inside this method.
I take my events from a min priority queue, where the peek Event should be the closest Event to location on the x-axis.Then I add it to the maxPriorityQueue that holds the closest Events, if its size is lower than 5, or its peek manDistance is higher than the Event compared to. If I reach an event with x higher than manDistance of the peek Event from my maxPriorityQueue, then I found my closest 5 events.

pqTemp - holds all events in a minPriorityQueue where peek is closest to location on x axis

manDistanceFarthest --holds current closest events where peek is Event with max manhattan distance.

```
public void findClosestEvents(){
    int steps=1;
    PriorityQueue<Event> pqTemp=new PriorityQueue<>(xClosest);
    manDistFarthest.add(pqTemp.poll());
    while (!(pqTemp.isEmpty())){
        steps+=1;
        if (manDistFarthest.size()<5)
            manDistFarthest.add(pqTemp.poll());

        else if (Math.abs(pqTemp.peek().getxCord())>manDistFarthest.peek().calcManDistance(xLoc, yLoc))
            break;
        else
            if (pqTemp.peek().calcManDistance(xLoc, yLoc)<=manDistFarthest.peek().calcManDistance(xLoc, yLoc)){
                manDistFarthest.poll(); 
            manDistFarthest.add(pqTemp.poll());
        }
            else pqTemp.poll();
    }
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Checked {0} events out of {1}.",steps,xClosest.size()));

}
```

Comment: That cast to `int` in your comparator doesn't do what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see here is your cast to int. As an example if this delta less than 1 - you'll get 0 - which means equals - which is not true.
And I don't understand the whole picture. How do you use your Comparator in pqTemp? May be you have Comparable Event?

Comment: I have a different comparator there that i haven't posted

Comment: Should I return 1,0 and -1 instead of casting to int?